# Unable to change video attr. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, video, element, target

I was working on a menu to change my videojs source and it works partly. I can change my video source with `$video_obj.src` but i unable to change my tags like `nonHD` or even classes style `.vjs-poster`.

something I forgot?

```js
$("ul.dl-menu a").click(function() {
 
 var $myClass   =  $(this).attr("class");
 var $target         =  $(this).attr("id");
    var $content_path   = "~path~/media-video/";
 var $thumbs         = "~path~/media-video/thumbs/";

    if ($myClass === "library") {
     var $vid_obj        = videojs("div_video");
     var $video_div   = "div_video";
    }
    else {
     var $vid_obj        = videojs("div_video_awards");
     var $video_div   = "div_video_awards";
    }

 
      $vid_obj.ready(function() {
      $($video_div+'.poster').hide();
      $($video_div+'_html5_api').hide();
      $vid_obj.pause();
      $($video_div+'video source:nth-child(1)').attr("src",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');
   $vid_obj.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: $content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4' });
      $($video_div+'video').attr("src",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');
   $($video_div).attr("nonHD",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');
      $($video_div).attr("HD",$content_path+'mp4-720p/'+$target+'.mp4');
      $($video_div+'video').attr("HD",$content_path+'mp4-720p/'+$target+'.mp4');
      $($video_div+'video').attr("nonHD",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');
      $($video_div+'.vjs-poster').attr("style", 'background-image: url('+$thumbs+$target+'.jpg);');
      $($video_div+'.vjs-tech').attr("poster",$thumbs+$target+".jpg").show();
      $($video_div).attr('poster',$thumbs+$target+'.jpg');
      $($video_div).removeClass('vjs-playing').addClass('vjs-paused');
      var css = document.createElement("style");
   css.type = "text/css";
      css.innerHTML = ".vjs-control.vjs-HD-button { color: silver; font-weight:normal; text-shadow: 0 0 5em #fff;}";
      document.body.appendChild(css);
      HD1 = false;
      $vid_obj.load();

      $($video_div+'_html5_api').show();
      setTimeout(function(){
      $vid_obj.play();
      }, 0);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="div_video" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin vjs-big-play-centered" width="auto" height="auto" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" HD="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" nonHD="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" controls>
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
  <button class="dl-trigger">Menu</button>
  <ul class="dl-menu">
    <li><a class="library" href="javascript:;" id="MBHD0790-03">Into the Woods</a></li>
    <li><a class="library" href="javascript:;" id="MBHD0790-04">Kingsman</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, given this:

```
 $($video_div+'video').attr("nonHD",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');
```

you'd be doing

```
 $('video_divvideo').attr(....);
```

There's no `#`, so javascript will be looking for a tag like `<video_divvideo>` in the dom, which of course doesn't exist.

Maybe you want

```
 $('#' +$video_div).attr(...);
```

instead?

Comment: i tried that–– doesnt work

`$('#'+$video_div+ 'video')` or even  `$('#'+$video_div)`

Comment: @BerlinMoses: You need to do the same thing for every selector you’ve created that way. `$('#'+$video_div)`. It’d be better to just keep a reference to the element, though, and use `find` when you need to get the `<source>`.

Comment: `$('#xxx')` means "look for an element with ID xxx". Without `#` or `.`, javascript will look for an element NAMED "xxx". You don't have a `#` in any of your searches.

Comment: I did and doesn't work 1. `$('#' + $video_div + 'video:nth-child(1)').attr("src",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');` 2nd line. `$('#' + $video_div + 'video').attr("src",$content_path+'mp4/'+$target+'.mp4');`

Comment: you're still adding `video`, which means you're looking for an element with id `video_divvideo`, which doesn't exist... e.g. `<div id="video_divvideo">`.

Comment: i doing that because videojs creates video inside my `#video_div`. [image] (http://i.imgur.com/GyBgUVr.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78724/discussion-between-berlin-moses-and-marc-b).